# $qx^2-px-q=0$ has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory

Show that the equation ,
$$qx^2-px-q=0$$ 
has no integer solution, Where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$.

Or

Show that:-
$$\frac{ p \pm \sqrt{p^2+4q^2}}{2q}$$
is never an integer. Thanks!

Comment: How are $p,q$ related?

Comment: Just an idea: from Vieta's formula the product of the roots is $-1$

Comment: @Sky does not help, the solutions could be $-2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, for example.

Comment: @Peter Ah yes, you are right.

Comment: Counterexample: $p=2,q=3 \implies \frac{p\pm\sqrt{p^2+4q}}{2q} = \frac{2\pm\sqrt{2^2+4\cdot3}}{2\cdot3} = \frac{2\pm4}{6} = 1$.

Comment: @barakmanos it is $q^2$

Comment: @barakmanos That should be $4\cdot 3^2$ in that fraction.

Comment: @wythagoras: That $4q^2$ was originally $4q$!!!

Comment: @Stef They are not  related

Comment: @vito There exist $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the equation has integer roots. Say $p=3,q=2$ and one root comes out as $2$. So is the problem wrongly stated?

Answer (score 7):

The theorem isn't true.

$$2x^2-3x-2=(x-2)(2x+1)$$

In general, $(x-n)(nx+1) = nx^2-(n^2-1)x-n$ has integer root $n$.

These (and integer multiples of these) are all such polynomials, since we know that if $m$ is a root, then $\frac{-1}{m}$ is a root, so the two roots must satisfy $$m-\frac{1}{m}=\frac{m^2-1}{m}=\frac{p}{q}$$

Since $m^2-1$ and $m$ are relatively prime, this is in reduced form.

Answer (score 2):

There are no positive integer solutions if $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q > p$. More specifically $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $\pm q^2 \neq \pm p+1$. I think this is if and only if.

By the rational root theorem, if a rational solution exists, it takes the form $\alpha /\beta$ where $\alpha | q$, the constant term, and $\beta | q$, the leading term. In particular, this means that an integer solution must be an integer factor of $q$. Let $q=ab$ and let the integer solution be $b$. Note that $a$ or $b$ can be negative. Substituting gives

$$ab(b^2)-p(b)-ab=0$$
which simplifies to
$$ab^2-p-a=0$$
and finally
$$p=a(b-1)(b+1).$$

Now if $|a| \neq 1$, we have $|a| \;|\;p$ and $|a| \;|\;q$, which means it is a common divisor and hence violates the relative primeness of $p$ and $q$. If $a=\pm 1$, $b=\pm q$. So we'd have

$$q^3-pq-q=q(\pm q^2 \mp p-1)=0$$
or
$$\pm q^2 = \pm p +1.$$
This is impossible when $q > p$.

All the counterexamples given so far are of the form $q^2=p+1$. Actually, I think the only $p,q$ with integer solutions are of the form

$$\left( \frac{q}{\gcd(p,q)} \right)^2 = \frac{p}{\gcd(p,q)} + 1$$
or

$$\frac{p}{\gcd(p,q)} = \left( \frac{q}{\gcd(p,q)} \right)^2 + 1$$

Comment: More simply, either $x = 0, q=0$, or $x=\pm 1, p=0$, or $p = q (x - 1/x)$ and for $|x| \ge 2$, $|x - 1/x| \ge 3/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Vieta's equation:
$$x^{2}-\frac{p}{q}x-1 = 0$$.

Now consider the roots:
$$x_{1,2} = \dfrac{\frac{p}{q} + (\frac{p^{2}}{q^{2}}+ 4)^{1/2}}{2}$$

$p^{2} + 4q^{2}$ is integer if and only if, then $p,q$ in Pythogorian triangle.

So $(3k)^{2} + (4k)^2 = (5k)^2$, our sequence is $p^{2} + (2*q)^2 = \beta^{2}$

$2q = 4k$, or $2q = 3k$, so $q = 2k$, or $\frac{3}{2}k$ then $p = {3k, 4k}$

Consider the $\frac{p}{q}$ and if $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{3}{2}$ then roots are valid, then $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{8}{3}$ roots are valid (because of Vieta's). So the statment isn't true.

Comment: $x_{1} or x_{2} \in Q$

Comment: That only really shows that both solutions can't be natural. At lest, not without more work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Any integer $x > 1$ is a root in the case $p = x^2-1$, $q = x$.  Moreover, the only quadratics of this form that have $x$ as a root are multiples of this one.